# Adding Item to listpicker by loop

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I want to add items to listpicker control of toolkit. 
I am doing this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cstringl.Length; i++)
{
    listPickerCountrySignup.Items.Add(cstringl[i]);
}
```

and here is MY XAML.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPickerCountrySignup" SelectionChanged="listPickerCountry_SelectionChanged" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" FullModeHeader="Select Country" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="{StaticResource listPickerBrush}" Style="{StaticResource ListPickerStyle1}">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Width="300" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="24"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

But its not showing in UI as I have binding in XAML but item I am adding from code behind by loop. No item source binding. How I Can Show Item in That List..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some data binding.

```
ObservableCollection<T> ListPickerItems = new ObservableCollection<T>();
for (int i = 0; i < cstringl.Length; i++)
{
    ListPickerItems .Add(cstringl[i]);
}
```

in Xaml:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource={Binding ListPickerItems} ... />
```

Comment: Or just listPickerCountrySignup.ItemsSoruce = cstringl; But the first solution is better.

Comment: I dont want any kind of binding.. Is there any other way without binding

Comment: but in XAML How my textblock will get data.. See my XAML as well

Comment: Via binding: Text="{Binding Country}" (This "cstringl" must have some kind of object items, which has a public property called "Country")

Comment: ListPickerItems.Add(cstringl[i]); but here is we are adding to just observable collection. Not to any country type property in my collection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13737/discussion-between-arslan-pervaiz-and-laszlokiss88)